# How can I get the total number of observations per (<field> = <value>) in R? (e.g. total number of observations per Date)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to create a graph in R, with Date on the Y axis, and total observations on that date / number of a specific observations on the X-axis. However, I'm not sure how to get the total number of observations per date.

```
ggplot(aes = (x = Date, y = (<number_of_observations> / (colour = 'Red'))), 
              data = cardata) +
      geom_histogram()
```

How can I do this, so I can get a number of specific observations? (e.g. so I can compare the number of Red cars with the total number of cars)

Comment: Do you want Dates on the Y or X axis? You wrote Y, but in the code you define `x = Date`. In most cases, time is displayed on the X axis. Can you provide sample data?

Comment: Sorry, I meant X Axis.

Comment: You should edit your question accordingly. What about sample data?

Comment: You probably want to use `geom_bar()` rather than `geom_histogram()` but without sample data I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I am following your question, but the `dplyr` package would suggest something like this.  Without some sample data it is hard to be more precise:

```
df <- data %.%
  group_by(Date) %.%
  summarise(DateObservations = length(Date) %.%
  summarise(DatePct = DateObservation/nrow(data)
```

Then you could ggplot it:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = DatePct) + geom_bar()
```

Comment: Quick notes: your `summarise` statements are incomplete, dplyr now uses %>% although %.% is also still working, using `n()` instead of `length(date)` would be more idiomatic in dplyr, by using two separate `summarise` you ungroup the only grouping variable (date) in the second `summarise`. Last but not least, in `geom_bar()` you would probably need to specify `stat = "identity"`.

Comment: @beginneR, thank you very much.  Just to be clear, I thought you had to load another package (named something like magritte) to use %>% in dplyr.  Nice point on n().  If I chain summarise, does the ungroup issue get resolved (and I don't understand why the groups can't have the two summarise columns.  Nice point on geom_bar().  I was just trying to sketch the approach, but you are correct.

Comment: When using the more/most recent versions of dplyr, you don't need to load magrittr additionally to use %>%. From `?group_by`: "summarise peels off a single layer of grouping" That means, if you use it twice and your data is grouped by a single variable, the second summarize will not use any groups. I think what you want is simply two columns in the first summarise, which you can do like this: `summarise(DateObservations = length(Date), DatePct = DateObservation/nrow(data))`. So essentially you are only using summarise once here.

Answer (score 1):

Try:
    ggplot(aes = (x = Date, data = cardata[cardata$colour == 'red'])) + geom_histogram()

So you filter on your condition when you define the data.